# Using Regex and Delimiters to Extract Data

Tags: java, regex, extract

How would I go about extracting all the characters between %3B and %2C using regular expression

```
%3B09573000P%2C%3B0906000P%2C%3B09593000P%2C%3B09512100P
```

So, I'm trying to extract strings that end with 'P' from below.  *Important to note they always won't end with P, so I have to base the extraction with %3B and %2C.

```
%3B
09573000P
%2C%3B
0906000P
%2C%3B
09593000P
%2C%3B
09512100P
```

I've tried the following, but have had no success.

```
'[(^%3B)(^%2B)]'


'%3B(.*)%2C'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `%3B(.*)%2C` is that `*` is "greedy", in the sense that it would go on capturing `%`, `2`, `C`, and so on. You can change that by making it *reluctant*, like this:

```
%3B(.*?)%2C
```

This solution is not so good on long strings, though, because it is prone to [*catastrophic backtracking*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). You can improve the performance if you know for sure that the content between the tags is not going to contain `%` characters:

```
%3B([^%]*)%2C
```

If you would like to capture the trailing string as well, add `|$` to the end marker:

```
%3B([^%]*)(?%2C|$)
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Jpfkye)